# Trouble with exporting data with rows and columns switched

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I am trying to export a non-rectangular nested list of data as an xlsx spreadsheet. If I export an un-nested list, it shows up as a single column. However when I go to export the nested list, it makes each sublist a row where I would like each sublist to be a column. My datasets are large and XLSX has a limit on the number of columns, so Mathematica will not even attempt the export and instead throws error `Export::toomany3`. This means I cannot swap the rows for columns in Excel. Furthermore, Mathematica won't let me transpose before exporting since the list is not rectangular. I can export the data as a CSV then use an online tool to transpose it, but it just seems like there's got to be a simple way to get Mathematica to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
data = Table[Range[i], {i, {51125, 26336, 10932, 3834, 1579}}];(*Example data*)
Export["data.xlsx", data[[1]]] (* Gives me a spreadsheet with 1 column *)
Export["data.xlsx", data] (* Tries to export data[[i]] as row instead of column *)
(* throws error because exceeds column number limit for xlsx *)
```

**Solution**
provided by george2079:

```
Export["data.xlsx", Function[{cols}, Transpose[PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ cols], ""] & /@ cols]]@data]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: pad all the lists so they are the same length (`PadRight`), then transpose, then export.  I think if you pad with empty strings excel will be happy.

Comment: I am new here so I appreciate the advice @m_goldberg. I have edited the question as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following my comment here is how to use `PadRight`

```
c1 = {1, 2}
c2 = {3, 4, 5}
Export["test.xls", 
  Function[{cols}, 
    Transpose[PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ cols], ""] & /@ cols]]@{c1,c2}]
```

( verified the "" pad gives an empty cell in excel )

also if you don't mind padding with zeros even more simply:

```
Export["test.xls", Transpose@PadRight@{c1, c2}]
```

unfortunately you can't specify the pad element with the array form of `PadRight`

Answer (score 2):

First, you must convert your rows to columns. For instance:

```
data1 = {#} & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 51125];
data2 =  {#} & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 26336];
```

then, export:

```
Export["data.xlsx", "Sheets" -> {"random 1" -> data1, "random 2" -> data2}, "Rules"]
```

Comment: Alternative way to convert a list to a column: `dataColumn = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 1}, 51125]}]`

Comment: This gives each column in a separate sheet which is closer to what I am trying to do but is still inconvenient to work with. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: You want to export the data as columns in the same sheet? If so the modification of `Export` should be easy.